# Jquery get width of an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am using the following jquery code to get the width of an SVG element when clicked on it and write it to the console. I get nothing on the console but no error as well. I am thinking this is because I am not passing the id correctly to the jquery selector. Not really sure though. Below is the code:

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
  if (this.id != 'main_svg') {
    a1 = this.id;
    console.log($(a1).width());
    $('svg').unbind('click');
    console.log(a1);
    getdiv2();
  }
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hzp8utu6/

Comment: @user2744722 The log says 0

Comment: Please create a fiddle. If it is working for others, but it is not working for your code, then there are other parts of your code that are incorrect.

Comment: @Arihant console says the exact svg width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
  if (this.id != 'main_svg') {
    a1 = this.id;
    console.log($("#" + a1).attr("width"));
    $('svg').unbind('click');
    console.log(a1);
  }
});
```

Comment: the console says 0

Comment: it shows 100 for me ..add alert as well ..check it once now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
    if( $(this).attr("id") != 'main_svg' ){
        a1=$(this).attr("id");
        console.log($(this).css("width"));
        $('svg').unbind('click');
        console.log(a1);
        getdiv2();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("svg").one("click", function() {
  if (this.id != 'main_svg') {
    a1 = this.id;
    console.log($('#' + a1).width());
    $(this).unbind('click');
    console.log(a1);
    //getdiv2();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100" height="100" id=main_svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" id=second_svg>
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" fill="blue" />
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" id="third_svg">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" stroke="purple" stroke-width="2" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Just add `'#'` before `id`. Use `$('#' + a1).width()`. You already using `.one()` that mean it will trigger only once so no need to use `.unbind('click')`

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
  if (this.id != 'main_svg') {
    a1 = this.id;
    console.log($('#' + a1).width());
    $(this).unbind('click');
    console.log(a1);
    getdiv2();
  }
});
```

Comment: the console says 0